# Can kinematic equations of motion be considered as a statistical model?

Tags: modeling

The motion of a car (*or a car relative to a lead car*) can be modeled using kinematic equations of motion as described below:

[image: source: thecuriousastronomer]

where,

for single car (*for a pair of cars*)

- *u* = inital speed (*or initial speed difference*)
- *v* = final speed (*or final speed difference*)
- *a* = acceleration (*or acceleration difference*)
- *t* = time
- *s* = displacement (*or distance between the front bumper of the following car and rear bumper of the lead car*)

To me, it looks like that equation 1 is a simple regression model with *u* as an intercept and *a* as a slope. Thus, the explanatory variable is time. As time goes on, the values of *v* and *s* change, depending on the value of *a*.

However, one stark difference between equation 1 and simple linear regression is that the intercept remains the same in the latter, but not in equation 1. This is because equation 1 is evaluated at every time frame (say 1 second). So, e.g. at *t* = 0, if *u* = 0 and *a* = 1, then *v* = 0. At *t* = 1, *v* = 1. At *t* = 2, the *u* is now equal to old *v* i.e. 1 and *v* gets updated to 2. In simple words, the speed is updated by 1 m/s every second because the acceleration rate is 1m/s per second.

Apart from this, the acceleration *a* does not necessarily remains constant. It can change sign (braking, pushing gas pedal) and/or change magnitude (driving freely or in heavy traffic) depending on the conditions and the driving style.

Therefore, in my opinion, **time is a confounding factor** in this case. My question is:

If one has to define a **statistical** model that captures car motion (with or without reference to a lead vehicle), what would be the best way to go about it? What framework should be used? My experience in statistical modeling has been limited to regression modeling only.

NOTE: I am aware of the body of literature on car-following models. But I'm interested in a statistical approach to look at this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're confounding, a bit, (1) cross-sectional regression and time series regression; and (2) deterministic and stochastic models. Equation (1) is your "core" equation; equation 2, for example, is simply its integral.  All other equations are simply restatements from Newtonian mechanics using a different parameterization.

So, in eq. #1, you are stating that (1)  a is constant (implicitly); (2) u(0) is known; (3) and v(0) is known.  It is simple physics then to determine v(t) assuming u(t) is known.  In fact, if a(t) is not a constant but known functionally, that, too, can be worked in.

It is a very different question to say that u(0) is known only as a random variable and u(t) is the same.  (Let's assume a(t) is a constant.)  Then you could use regression.

To understand what is going on, you must get beyond  regression alone, and learn mathematical statistics: the calculus of (formally defined) random variables.  Regression can be explained via mathematical statistics, but not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What do you recommend I should learn to model this behavior? You mentioned mathematical statistics. Is it different from regular statistics? Any good resources that you'd like to recommend?

Comment: Any intro book should be fine.  Feller's "Introduction to Probabiliy Theory" is the classic.